# How to connect fields from Cognito user to Strapi user

Tags: typescript, amazon-cognito, strapi

I have setup Strapi and connect to AWS Cognito using their Users & Permissions Plugin.

I want to have first, last name and gender on my Cognito users

[image]

I expanded the Users Content-Type to have those fields as well

[image]

**When I register a new user those fields just don't get filled out by default**

I haven't found a way to configure that by reading the documentation and I feel like there has to be some way to access this built in plugin and override method somehow to allow me to expand on what is going to be mapped on my Strapi users.

There is a pretty well made docs for startup, but lacks the customization details [here][3].

Anyone have any ideas?

[3]: [https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/users-permissions.html#providers:~:text=ngrok.io%27](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/users-permissions.html#providers:%7E:text=ngrok.io%27))%2C).-,%23,Setting%20up%20the%20provider%20%2D%20examples,-Instead%20of%20a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue I made a post-authentication trigger in cognito, which when performing authentication it makes a POST and updates the user-permissions fields in Strapi.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).